# Pair RDD Transformations

Tags: scala, apache-spark

If I have a data set similar to this:

`val list = List ( (1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (2,2), (2,1), (3,1), (3,3) )`

And I want to find the average per-key so the output should be:

`(1, 2), (2, 3/2), (3, 2)` can I do this using `groupByKey, countByKey, and reduceByKey` somehow or do I have to use combineByKey method similar to the example showed below: I tried using `groupByKey, countByKey, and reduceByKey` but this combination of methods do not work out, I was wondering if anyone knows a way to do it using those three methods?

```
val result = input.combineByKey(
(v) => (v, 1),
(acc: (Int, Int), v) => (acc._1 + v, acc._2 + 1),
(acc1: (Int, Int), acc2: (Int, Int)) => (acc1._1 + acc2._1, acc1._2 + acc2._2)).  
map{ case (key, value) => (key, value._1 / value._2.toFloat) } 

result.collectAsMap().map(println(_))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try the following:

```
val sc: SparkContext = ...
val input = sc.parallelize(List((1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (2,2), (2,1), (3,1), (3,3)))
val averages = input.groupByKey.map { case (key, values) =>
  (key, values.sum / values.size.toDouble)
}

println(averages.collect().toList) // List((1,2.0), (2,1.5), (3,2.0))
```

Comment: Oh right I forgot when you groupByKey it puts the values in an array so you can use sum and size on that array! Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Well you can simply use [PairRDDFunctions.groupByKey](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions) and compute what you want.

```
val avgKey = input.groupByKey.map{
  case (k, v) => (k, v.sum.toDouble/v.size)
}
avgkey.collect
//res2: Array[(Int, Double)] = Array((3,2.0), (1,2.0), (2,1.5))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `reduceByKey`, with prior transformation of the *duples* into *triplets*,

```
rdd.map{ case(k,v) => (k,(v,1)) }.
    reduceByKey( (a,v) => (a._1+v._1, a._2+v._2)).
    map {case (k,v) => (k, v._1 / v._2)}
```

Comment: Hello elm! Sorry for the late reply, but can you please explain when you would use `case` inside of a map function? Is it just so that you can write the parameters as `(k,v)` instead of having to specify specifically how `k` and `v` are structured. For example if `k` was a tuple, without the case in the map I would have to write `( (a1,a2), v)`? So it is technically just for pattern matching?

Comment: With `case` we *enable* pattern matching, for extracting or decomposing data structures, and we use curly brackets to define a partial function (not all the patterns need be defined). On the other hand, the use of a tuple data structure involves the use of its own methods (._1 and ._2) to obtain (extract) the items of the data.